# MaterialApp builder error : No Overlay widget found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm getting error on building navigationDrawer where tootlip widget needs materialApp as ancestor.

here is what error says :

```
I/flutter ( 5780): _TooltipState#bc79e(ticker inactive)):
I/flutter ( 5780): No Overlay widget found.
I/flutter ( 5780): Tooltip widgets require an Overlay widget ancestor for correct operation.
I/flutter ( 5780): The most common way to add an Overlay to an application is to include a MaterialApp or Navigator
I/flutter ( 5780): widget in the runApp() call.
I/flutter ( 5780): The specific widget that failed to find an overlay was:
I/flutter ( 5780):   Tooltip
I/flutter ( 5780): 
I/flutter ( 5780): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 5780):   AppBar
```

my **main.dart** code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ... //basic info title & theme

      builder: (context, child) => LayoutTemplate(child: child),
      initialRoute:"/home",

      ... //Routing stuff like generate route & navigator key 
    );
  }
}
```

**LayoutTemplate Widget**

```
class LayoutTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const LayoutTemplate({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("home"))
        drawer: NavDrawer()
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            //NavigationBar(),
            Expanded(
              child: child,
            )
          ],
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

sorry for adding too much code. I'm not sure what causing the issue. maybe the `builder` from `MaterialApp` is causing it.

thank you for helping.

Comment: Always post a minimal reproducible code which we can run locally, how do we know what's your `sl`, `NavigationService`, `sizingInformation`, `Routes.clientList`, etc etc. Almost every line of your code uses a field defined in your project which you didn't share. You're almost 6 years old on SO, so post a MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE CODE which can be run by others.

Comment: I've tried to remove unnecessary code. please check updated question

Comment: Thanks, can you also work modify `initialRoute`, `onGenerateRoute` and `navigatorKey`?

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue with a TextField instead of a Tooltip. Did you find ny solution? I guess we're following the same tutorial!

Answer (score 30):

In your builder, just return an Overlay widget with the LayoutTemplate as OverlayEntry.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ... //basic info title & theme

      builder: (context, child) {
        return Overlay(
          initialEntries: [
            OverlayEntry(
              builder: (context) => LayoutTemplate(child: child),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
      initialRoute:"/home",

      ... //Routing stuff like generate route & navigator key 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solves the issue, thank you. Can you explain why the Overlay widget is required? I would expect either the MaterialApp or Scaffold would create an Overlay widget that can be used here.

Comment: Basically MaterialApp creates this Overlay behind the scenes, but whenever we use this "builder" parameter, everything that MaterialApp created by default is no longer created and has to be created manually within the "builder", including the Overlay.

Comment: Geneously! Solves all the problems related to overlays

Answer (score 6):

If you're using responsive_framework: ^0.1.4 package and you encountered that problem, heres the fix

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter App',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Overlay(
          initialEntries: [
            OverlayEntry(
              builder: (context) {
                return ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
                  MyHomePage(),
                  defaultScale: true,
                  breakpoints: [
                    ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1000),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works but if you were only to remove the arrow function and switch with a regular one in builder of the responsive framework demo, it also eliminates the error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use your `LayoutTemplate` widget in each of your routes:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // ... basic info title & theme

      initialRoute:"/home",
      routes: [
        '/home': (context) => LayoutTemplate(child: Text('Home')),
        // etc, for other routes
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

---

The builder parameter is best used for "inserting [[heritable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) widgets] above the `Navigator` or - when the `WidgetsApp.router` constructor is used - above the `Router` but below the other widgets created by the `WidgetsApp` widget, or for replacing the `Navigator`/`Router` entirely."

[`WidgetsApp.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsApp/builder.html) documentation:

> For example, from the `BuildContext` passed to [route builder methods], the `Directionality`, `Localizations`, `DefaultTextStyle`, `MediaQuery`, etc, are all available. They can also be overridden in a way that impacts all the routes in the Navigator or Router.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed this by using home instead of the builder parameter

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      ... //basic info title & theme

      home: LayoutTemplate(child: child),
      initialRoute:"/home",

      ... //Routing stuff like generate route & navigator key 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Using builder(...) is a valid way to build a page and it shouldn't fail if you're adding an AppBar to a Scaffold that is created in that builder.